# Thermal ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics

Consider a system of $N$ fermions in a periodic box $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, described by the Hamiltonian
$$H_{N} = \sum_{k=1}^{N}(-\Delta_{x_{k}}-\mu) + \lambda \sum_{i< j}V(x_{i}-x_{j}) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\lambda$ is some coupling constant, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ is the chemical potential and $V$ is a sufficiently well-behaved interaction function. After second quantization, we consider the fermionic Fock space described by a second quantized Hamiltonian $H$.

Suppose we have a theory in finite temperature $\beta = 1/T > 0$. Let $\psi_{x}^{\pm}$ be creation and annihilation operators for fermions and, for $\beta \ge t_{i}$, $i=1,...,n$, $t_{i}\neq t_{j}$ for $i \neq j$, define the $n$-point (real time) Green's function:
$$S_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}, \beta}(x_{1},t_{1},...,x_{n},t_{n}) := (-1)^{\pi}\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-(\beta-t_{\pi(1)})H}\psi_{x_{\pi(1)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(1)}}e^{-(t_{\pi(1)}-t_{\pi(2)})H}\psi_{\pi(2)}^{\sigma_{\pi(2)}}\cdots \psi_{x_{\pi(n)}}^{\sigma_{\pi(n)}}e^{-t_{\pi(n)}H})}{\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta H}}. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Here, $\sigma = \pm 1$, $\pi$ is a permutation of $\{1,...,n\}$ such that $t_{\pi(1)} > t_{\pi(2)} > \cdots > t_{\pi(n)}$ and $(-1)^{\pi}$ is the parity of $\pi$.

Regarding the Schwinger functions:

1. In [this book](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691044460/renormalization-group), the authors claim that (\ref{2}) describe the *ground state* of the associated fermi system.
2. In section 3, point 3.2 of [this review](https://inspirehep.net/literature/566029), the authors claim that one can obtain information about the *spectrum* of the Hamiltonian from (\ref{2}).

I have been searching the physics and mathematical physics literature for justifications of both these bullet points. However, I found nothing. In the many-body physics books I know, the only discussion in this direction regards perturbation theory. But this is a slightly different approach than the one I am presenting above. First, it is mainly focused on **two** point (Green) functions, not $n$-point functions. In addition, one wants to calculate this Green function by a perturbative series. In this case, an $n$-point function arises (for instance, in the Dyson series), but then these $n$-point functions are with respect to the **free** theory, not the interacting one as in (\ref{2}).

Can someone *please* clarify where the both claims come from? Or maybe point me to the literature (in the context of many-body quantum mechanics/many fermions systems, not general QFT) where these questions are addressed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the ground state expectations you need to set $\beta\to \infty$ (zero temperature). You can read off the spectrum by focussing on just two opertors $\psi(p, t_1)$ and $\psi(p,t_2)$ and looking at how the fourier transform $x\to p$ two-point function behaves at the $t$'s separate:
$$
\langle \psi(p,t_1) \psi^\dagger(p,t_2)\rangle\propto  e^{-(t_2-t_1) E(p)}.
$$
Here $E(p)$ is the energy at momentum $p$ by a state with quantum numbers (spin, charge etc) such that it can be created by $\psi^\dagger(x)$.

Comment: Mike thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate just a bit more on this formula? Is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the time-zero vacuum expectation? And where does your formula come from? Is it easy to deduce or is there some deep machinery behind it?

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure what you know to start with. Also I am not sure why you need the permutations. The usual $n$-point thermal functions are either (imaginary) time ordered (Matsubara fomalism) which is what a path integral gives  so the ordering is automatic, or not ordered at all (KMS-type) correlators. Perhaps you should give the actual pages where your unusual  formula  appears.

Comment: Mike, it is page 12 (first page of chapter 3) in Gallavotti's book.

Comment: Sadly I can't find an online copy that I can access. Is there an ArXiv link to the review?

Comment: This is very confusing to me. If I have a many-body system, I would guess one wants to compute the free energy or partition function, and then one can use path integrals. If one wants to compute it perturbatively, then one expands in the interaction fields. However, Gallavotti **starts** from this $n$-point Schwinger function as the primary object of interest. And the average is with respect to the interaction picture. The problem is I don't know why it should be the primary object of interest. In other words, what do we want with it? I thought points 1. and 2. of my question were the reason.

Comment: The review has open access on one of the author's webpage. I can get access via the link: /http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/gentile/ricerca/lavori/gm5.pdf

Comment: Oh, I just realized the permutation makes the time ordered. It was my mistake not to include it here. I will edit the post.

Comment: I found the book eventually. The statement that these are grouind state Schwinger functions is wrong an misleading. They are Thermal Schwinger functions.   I' look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_function